# Check for a hidden form variable in a view

Tags: django, django-forms

I have several forms each having a hidden field that identifies this form...I want to check for this field in my view then based on the result determine which form will be processed.  How should i go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the data is passed to the view in the post you should be able to grab it:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if "hidden_field_name" in request.POST:
        ## do something
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be using [Django Forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/). They are very powerful and quite extensible.

Comment: This is what I'm using...thnks